# How to handle dropped columns entries in re-run in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Im doing data migration form table1 to table 2 and drop some columns once the data migration is completed. But when i re-run the script again it is giving undeclared identifier for the dropped column.

Ex:

```
table 1 has column test1, test2, test3
table 2 has column col1, col2, col3
```

Now im filling table2 using table 1 data's

```
cursor cur select * from table1  
loop
inserting into col1, col2, col3 values (cur.test1, cur.test2, cur.test3);
end loop;
```

and now drop column test3 from table1.

This works fine for the first and in the second run cur.test3 will not be available and giving col.test3 as undeclared identifier.

How to fix this issue

Comment: Well... Do not drop the column. Please, clarify why you are dropping the column and still trying to use this column.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run a script referencing a column that does not exist. Either:

1. Do not drop the column.
2. If you do drop the column then edit the script to remove the dropped column so it becomes syntactically valid before you try to run it.
3. If you do drop the column then recreate the column before running the script so it becomes syntactically valid before you try to run it.
4. Convert all the queries to dynamic SQL (so that the queries are not checked at compile time but will be evaluated at run-time) and then catch any errors relating to missing columns. However, this option seems like an over-reaction to the issue that should be solved with option #1, #2 or #3.